# Hints are not allowed on recursive common table expression (CTE) references. Consider removing hint from recursive CTE reference 'CTE'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have one Employee table here is table structure

```
Name    varchar
GUID    numeric
ParentGUID  numeric
```

here is some sample data

```
NAME GUID ParentGUID
ABC    1   NULL
BCD    2   1
xyz    3   2
PQR    4   2
MRS    5   3
```

This table contains big hierarchy of Employee and manager.
I need to pick all the Employee coming under particular employee.
Ex. I need all the Employees coming under BCD, so result should be

```
 xyz    3   2
 PQR    4   2
```

here is my recursive query for that.

```
;WITH CTE (Name, GUID, ParentGUID)
    AS
    (
    select distinct B.Name , B.GUID,  B.ParentGUID
    FROM 
    EMP B with (nolock)     

    union All

    select a.Name , a.GUID, a.ParentGUID
    FROM EMP a with (nolock)
    inner join CTE C with (nolock)  on a.ParentGUID = c.GUID
    )
    select *
    FROM CTE B with (nolock)     where B.Name in ('BCD')
```

But it's giving me error.

```
Msg 4150, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Hints are not allowed on recursive common table expression (CTE) references. Consider removing hint from recursive CTE reference 'CTE'.
```

Can you anyone please help me to correct this query.

Comment: Well you could remove the WITH(NOLOCK) as the error states...

Comment: Thanks, S.karras After removing WITH(NOLOCK), i am getting just 1 records, i am not getting complete hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `where B.Name in ('BCD')` is what is filtering your result set to just the one row.  Change it to the below and you should get the results you want:

```
;with cte (Name, GUID, ParentGUID)
    as
    (
    select distinct B.Name
                   ,B.GUID
                   ,B.ParentGUID
    from EMP B
    where B.Name in ('BCD')

    union All

    select a.Name
          ,a.GUID
          ,a.ParentGUID
    from EMP a
        inner join CTE C
            on a.ParentGUID = c.GUID
    )
    select *
    from CTE
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, @iamdave for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Completely removing the `WITH (NOLOCK)` only solve the error,
to use `WITH (NOLOCK)` in recursive CTE you just need to put it outside of WITH clause only

```
;with cte (Name, GUID, ParentGUID)
    as
    (
    select distinct B.Name
                   ,B.GUID
                   ,B.ParentGUID
    from EMP B
    where B.Name in ('BCD')

    union All

    select a.Name
          ,a.GUID
          ,a.ParentGUID
    from EMP a
        inner join CTE C
            on a.ParentGUID = c.GUID
    )
    select *
    from cte WITH (NOLOCK);
```

Comment: This would make more sense as a comment on the previous answer, since you're really suggesting an additional modification to that answer.